# VHDL - Convert string into a 32 bit integer

Tags: string, file, integer, vhdl

I've a text file that contains expected output of a computation and a vhdl testbench with a module under test that make the computation. The idea is to compute the output of the module with the expected output inside the file.

The module works on 32 bit and the file contains a list (line by line) of integer values on max 32 bit. The problem is that I wrote a fragment of code that make a comparison between each output of the module and each output of the file, but it gives me a strange error.

The code is this one:

```vhdl
process

        
        variable line_v : line;
        file read_file : text;
        variable read_int : integer;
        variable read_string: string(1 to 10); --Max integer on 32 bit is 4294967295: 10 chars

begin


        file_open(read_file, "mat2.mem", read_mode);
        for i in 0 to 31 loop
            for j in 0 to 31 loop
                readline(read_file, line_v);
                read(line_v, read_string);
              
                row <= std_logic_vector(TO_UNSIGNED(i, row'length));
                col <= std_logic_vector(TO_UNSIGNED(j, col'length));
                wait for 2 ns; -- after 2 ns, I have the result available on 32 bit std_logic_vector "data"
                
                assert unsigned(data) = integer'value(read_string) report "ERROR! Result not equal to expected one!";
                
            end loop;
        end loop;

        file_close(read_file);

end process;
```

The error I receive is this one (data contains 3413424693 according to the simulator):

**ERROR: value string "3413424693" could not be interpreted as integer type**

How can i solve this?

Thank you

Comment: EEE Std 1076-2008 16.2 Predefined attributes of types and objects, T'VALUE(X) "Restrictions: It is an error if the parameter is not a valid string representation of a literal of type T or if the result does not belong to the subtype implied by T." The range of INTEGER in a particular implementation is determinable from the values of its 'LOW and 'HIGH attributes." Provide a [mcve]. How can i solve this? Consider packages numeric_bit or numeric_std and a read procedure with an output that is a unsigned type. The input would be a text field in the form of a bit string literal.

Comment: The equivalent of Synopsys package std_logic_textio has been incorporated into the respective -2008 packages std_logic_1164 and numeric_std. Synopsys package std_logic_textio and -2008 numeric_std contain a read for type unsigned. In -2008 bit string literals may have a decimal base as well as a length prefix. Otherwise binary, octal or hex.

Answer (score 3):

***How can i solve this?***

As you can see from the comments and other answer there isn't a 32 bit unsigned integer value range defined in VHDL. If there were it would be vendor implementation dependent and non-portable. Without waiting for a -2019 implementation with integers of a 64 bit range (-2008 has no complete implementations to date) it's worth exploring other options.

There appear to be two basic workarounds. Use a read procedure that can read in a std_logic_vector (or unsigned value) with a length of 32 or deal with the integer value in smaller increments. The read procedure solutions either come from Synopsys package std_logic_textio or the -2008 IEEE package numeric_std (unsigned) or package std_logic_1164 (std_logic_vector). These would require the values read be bit string literals or strings of 1s and 0s (not abstract literals).

A method of dealing with smaller integers can be demonstrated. Here the idea is two convert the integer value to unsigned in smaller values, here decimal digits and do all the math as unsigned.

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package dec_conv is
    function dec2slv(s: string; l: positive := 32) return std_logic_vector;
end package dec_conv;

package body dec_conv is
    function dec2slv(s: string; l: positive := 32) return std_logic_vector is
        variable decade:    positive := 1;
        variable result:   unsigned (l - 1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    begin
        for i in s'reverse_range loop
            result := result + resize (
                      (to_unsigned(natural'value("" & s(i)), l) * decade)
                      , l);
            decade := decade * 10;
        end loop;
        return std_logic_vector(result);
    end function;
end package body;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.dec_conv.all;

entity dec2slv_tst is
end entity;

architecture foo of dec2slv_tst is
    signal data:    std_logic_vector (31 downto 0) := x"cb74ba35";
begin
    assert data = dec2slv("3413424693")
        report "ERROR"
        severity ERROR;
end architecture;
```

The function can produce any length std_logic_vector from any length string consisting of the characters representing the numeric values 0 - 9. Note there's no checking to determine the specified length of either are compatible and it could generate errors. the length is specified by `l` which has a default value (which makes it optional to specify in the function call). It would work with your maximum unsigned integer value of 4294967295 signified by all '1's in a length 32 vector.

The use of reverse_range starts at the LS digit. Note an alias for the string input value can be use here to insure `s` has a rising range (type string has a deferred range). The alias can specify the subtype indication and always provide a rising range and be use in place of `s` in the subprogram body. The resize function call is to take the lower `l` length product of the multiply of and assign it to `result`. `decade` is used as a weight value for each digit right to left.

The amount of execution effort using this method is roughly on par with using a read procedure reading bit string literals (which in -2008 can be decimal).

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the `std.standard` package, you'll see:

```
type INTEGER is range -2147483647 to 2147483647;
```

3413424693 is greater than 2147483647. Hence your error. Basically, this comment is not true:

```
--Max integer on 32 bit is 4294967295
```

It should be:

```
--Max integer on 32 bit is 2147483647
```

Comment: Also note that this is not quite the full 32 bit range. -2^31 is not covered (min value is -2^31+1) If you can find a tool that implements VHDL 2019, then integer has been increased to 64 bits.

Comment: Not quite accurate. IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2.3.2 Predefined integer types
"The only predefined integer type is the type INTEGER. The range of INTEGER is implementation dependent, but it is guaranteed to include the range –2147483647 to +2147483647. It is defined with an ascending range."
"NOTE—The range of INTEGER in a particular implementation is determinable from the values of its 'LOW and 'HIGH attributes."  16.3 Package STANDARD "**type** INTEGER **is range** *implementation_defined*;" There's a portability issue outside the guaranteed range.

Comment: ghdl - "type integer is range -2147483648 to 2147483647;"